# Why is logrotate not automatically rotated?

Tags: logrotate

I've set you up to rotate daily, but you don't.

But when I do it manually, it does work.

```
logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.conf
```

This is my log file to rotate. /mylogs/log (-rwxrwxrwxrwx 1 admin admin)

This is the system configuration.

`/etc/logrotate.conf (-rw-r--r-- 1 root root)`:

```
/mylogs/log {
create 0640 root utmp
missingok
daily
copytruncate
rotate 10
dateext
}
```

`/etc/logrotate.d/syslog (-rw-r--r-- 1 root root)`:

```
/var/log/cron
/var/log/maillog
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
/var/log/spooler
{
missingok
sharedscripts
postrotate
/bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || 
true
endscript
}
```

`/etc/cron.daily/logrotate (-rwx------ 1 root root)`:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status /etc/logrotate.conf
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
/usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with 
[$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

`/etc/crontab (-rw-r--r--. 1 root root)`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR 
sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
```

*Additional information.
CentOS operating system*

How can I get it to rotate properly.

---

### UPDATE

I think the problem is in assigning owner, group and permissions of 3 things.
The /mylogs/        folder (root root)
The /mylogs/log file (admin admin)
The create option of logrotate.conf (create 0640 root utmp)

Someone with logrotate running correctly. Please let me know how you have assigned the previous 3 values. the folder - the file - the create config in logrotate.conf

Comment: Can you provide information how do you "run manually"? At the moment I can see you have different file ownership in different places.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I added the line that I run manually.

Comment: Did you look at your logfiles, you should see some cron activity telling you it executes logrotate each day.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to check what you tell me, I'll see if I can get the information to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after several tests I managed to get it to rotate correctly again.

To do this, I have assigned the user (root) and group (root) of the log file.

Also change your permissions to 666.

With respect to the folder containing the file, it is assigned a user (root) of group (root) and 755 permissions.

Finally within the configuration of logrotate.conf the configuration assigned to this property 'create' was user (root), group (utmp) and permissions (644)

I hope this information will be useful in case someone has a similar problem.

Greetings and thank you.

Comment: You should not have permissions 666, instead you should use 644. With the 'w' flag as "other" (the 006 represents ------rw-) which means anyone on that computer can temper with your file.

Answer (score 0):

Join two strings here

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status 
/etc/logrotate.conf
```

To one string like this one:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Or put backslash after first string, like this:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status \
/etc/logrotate.conf
```

p.s.
there is an excellent option `-x` for `/bin/sh` to make debug output from shell, and I guess you'll be able to find this mistype next time if you'd try to run `/bin/sh -x /etc/cron.daily/logrotate`

Comment: In the configuration file is written correctly, I have pasted it wrong in the post, now I correct it. Thank you very much

Comment: ok. @xav So next guess: is there `/var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status` file and folder for it: `/var/lib/logrotate/` ? Logrotate may skip rotating logs if there is no such folder. And also there may be some notes about errors on state file. Please check it for any warnings.

Comment: Hello, the folder and file exist. There are no warnings or error messages inside. /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status (-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin)

Comment: @xav are there any records about your `/mylogs` files in `status` file? You have `-s /var/lib/logrotate/status` on your cron file and by hands you run without it, this also may affect the way file is rotated. You also could use `-d` flag for logrotate to show what it will do without actual rotating and compare `-d` outputs for `-s /var/lib/logrotate/status` and without `-s` runs.

Comment: Hi this is using: -d [link](https://pastebin.com/2xdUSRbq)    And this without d or s  :error: error creating output file /mylogs/log-20171126: permission denied

Comment: I think the problem lies in assigning owners and groups of 2 things.
The /mylogs/        folder (root root)
The /mylogs/log file (admin admin)    
Bearing in mind that on logrotate.conf I have a "create 0640 root utmp"
By the way, I've changed the daily to 1M size. So I can test more often.

Comment: So you have run with `-d` and it's fine. Could run one more time with `-d -s /var/lib/logrotate/status` and paste output somewhere? As `-d` is for `debug` and means __do not actually rotate just show what will happens__. And I want to compare actions with state file and without. And running from your login without `-d` sure give you an error as your login doesn't have enough permissions.

Comment: Hi Fedor. [link]https://pastebin.com/GE21kkC1    I've put in a lot of tests here. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69306/discussion-between-xav-and-fedor-dikarev).

Comment: @xav it's 11pm now in Moscow and I have tennis game on Monday morning so have to wake up at 6:30 am. So I could reply you later, but in general: according to your logs your file will be rotated automaticly, you only have to wait until new day come. So lets wait for tommorow and we can continue in chat if problem still persits.

Comment: Thank you, Fedor. Have a good night. We'll talk tomorrow. Greetings.